# How to handle date stored as string in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, string, mongodb, datetime

So I have this field called `task_time` stored as string in Mongodb in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format (eg. '2012-12-21').

Now I need to query this collection to get the data whose `task_time` is within a given time interval.

The time interval is given as a pair of strings that represent start time and end time in `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` format (eg. '2015-12-21 16:00:00').

Is there any way to do this directly in Mongo query without bringing this task to my javascript code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I know `$gte` and `$lt` can work with strings too. The same in mongoose after [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/317)

```
items.find({
    task_time: {
        $gte: "2015-12-21 12:00:00",
        $lt: "2015-12-21 16:00:00" 
    }
})
```